# Using interfaces with entity framework 6

Tags: c#, interface, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, dbset

I have coded a C# MVC5 Internet application, and want to know if I can use interfaces with EF6, and if not, how else I should code my classes.

Here is what I have that does work:

```
public class TestObjectWithObjectList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TestObjectItem> items { get; set; }

    public TestObjectWithObjectList()
    {
        items = new List<TestObjectItem>();
    }
}
```

I have a `DbSet<TestObjectWithObjectList>`. When I add a `TestObjectWithObjectList` to the DbSet, I also add a `TestObjectItem` to the `List<TestObjectItem>`. When I retrieve the `TestObjectWithObjectList`, the `List<TestObjectItem>` has a count of 1.

Here is the same code, but with a `List<ITestObjectItem>`:

```
public class TestObjectWithInterfaceList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ITestObjectItem> items { get; set; }

    public TestObjectWithInterfaceList()
    {
        items = new List<ITestObjectItem>();
    }
}
```

I have a `DbSet<TestObjectWithInterfaceList>`. When I add a `TestObjectWithInterfaceList` to the DbSet, I also add a `TestInterfaceObjectItem` (that implements the `ITestObjectItem` interface) to the `List<ITestObjectItem>`. When I retrieve the `TestObjectWithInterfaceList`, the `List<ITestObjectItem>` has a count of 0.

Is it possible to get the above code to work with a `List<ITestObjectItem>`? What I want to do is to be able to add many objects to the `List<ITestObjectItem>`, and be able to retrieve them just by getting the `TestObjectWithInterfaceList` object.

Thanks in advance